# INET Building error

Tags: java, omnet++, inet

I have been using omnet++ 5 and inet 3.x and inetmanet 3.x. I have been encountering inet/inetmanet building error for a few days. before that it builds fine but took time for building.
The error is **Unhandled event loop exception
Java heap space**

I have tried these solutions but error is still there.

1. I have changed heap size to 2 gb( RAM size is also 2gb) in [omnetpp.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBHz7.png)
2. I have unchecked c/c++ Build-> Enable parallel build.

Please suggest me a solution for it. Some times when i restart the computer inet builds but took so much time for building. but after that it stopped building with the above error.

Comment: Does this also happen with clean clones of the original INET or only with modifications by you?

Comment: Yes it also happens with the clean clones too. Sometimes it built fine.